# Background image disappears in some browsers

Tags: html, css

```
.social_isExt {
    background-image: url("../img/bars/social_bar_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 175px;
}
```

I have this block of css typed, and it job is to widen a pic (1px in width) across a bar.

It shows correctly on firefox, and chrome, but the background image disappears when browsing the site with opera, or chromium. So i think that the path to the image is correct. More to the point; if i type down just the pics url, and go back to the front page (with opera or chromium), it shows the background image correctly..Keep in mind, that is shows correctly all the time with ff, and chrome.

Comment: Does it work if you take out the `..`?

Comment: Does the image disappear or does the element collapse?

Comment: @Andrew Morton i'm guessing it doesn't show anything, because the reference would be wrong. I have other pics from the same folder structure showing just fine..Only this one is acting up

Comment: @isherwood I have no idea, i'm not very good with css at all. How can i tell the difference? ..But i would say that it disappears..

Comment: Can you try change a name of image without underscore?

Comment: You need to get familiar with your browser's document inspector. It's invaluable for web developers and virtually eliminates troublesome questions like this. Check the dimensions of the element.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is showing in one browser and not the other the path is correct, it must be a positioning issue with either float or display.

Try this to see if adding display:block or display:inline-block fixes the issue

```
.social_isExt {
    background-image: url("../img/bars/social_bar_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 175px;
   display: block;
}
```

if that doesnt work add

```
.PARENTOFsocial_isExt {
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: nice idea, sadly nothing changed

Comment: try with inline-block?

Comment: Once again, something that i find most confusing. if i type in just the path of the image, and go back to the front page, it shows the bar nicely with every browser..

Comment: Your saying without any of the other style's just the background-image: url("../img/bars/social_bar_bg.jpg"); it works?

Comment: it has zero affect with  inline-block, and inline-flex

Comment: No, i'm saying that in some browsers it works like charm, like any other background-image would. To get it to show in with the ones that it doesn't work (opera and chromim), i have to go to the actual image file first, and then back to the front page, so it loads it correctly..

Comment: I think float and display mess with each other (cant remember) try removing float with display and position it with left:0

Comment: Try adding background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: Last attempt for me... try adding background-size: 1px auto;

Comment: No such luck. I tried that some time ago, and it didn't do anything. But like @isherwood said to check the inspector, i found out that the background image got filtered by adblock plus..I have no idea why, or how to get rid of it..

Comment: Sounds like you might just have an odd setup on your computer for those browsers... Try checking the code on a different computer or fresh install of the browsers

Answer (score 0):

I had an adblockplus extension, that filtered every source reference to a "social" word. By removing the "social" word from the img path, it started working like before.....The more you know :D

Answer (score 0):

You are fine with your codes & browsers.

Just **avoid to use some kind of keywords** in your css background path/name. Those which usually advertisers use to use.
Like: banner, bar, social, free, prize & so on...

**The ad-blocker is sensitive about those kind of words** as my experiences, specially in Opera and Chromium.